# $\sum_{m=-l, ....,l; l=0,1,2,..} e^{\frac{-i E_l (t_f-t_i)}{\hbar}} Y_{lm}(\phi_f,\theta_f)Y_{lm}(\phi_i, \theta_i)$

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

I have encountered this series while trying to calculate the path integral of a free particle on a sphere. The sum is $$K=\sum e^{\frac{-i E_l (t_f-t_i)}{\hbar}} Y_{lm}(\phi_f,\theta_f)Y_{lm}(\phi_i, \theta_i)$$ $E_l=\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}l(l+1)$, $\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}$ is a constant.

The sum over m is from $-m$ to $m$, and that over $l$ is over the natural numbers $1,2,3...$. $Y's$ are the spherical harmonics on two points of a sphere. The m sum can be done using the [addition theorem for spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Addition_theorem)

After doing this, the answer is $K(\theta, t_f-t_i) =  \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{2l+1}{4 \pi} e^{\frac{-\hbar^2}{2I} l(l+1)(t_f-t_i)}P_l(cos(\theta))$.

$\theta$ is the angle between the two position vectors i.e. $\cos{\theta}=\hat{n_f}\cdot \hat{n_i}$, where $n_f, n_1$ are the vectors to the two points.

**How do I do the sum over $l$**? I am stumped and no idea how to proceed.

Note: I had asked this question on Physics SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66076/calculation-of-the-spherical-harmonic-sum-in-the-propagator-of-the-particle-on-a/66091?noredirect=1#comment133325_66091), and got a response, but for the above sum the answer gives reference to a review, which is much beyond my understanding. I am wondering if there is a cute and quick method to do it, or a simplified summary of the method used in the review.

Comment: Is $\theta=\theta_f-\theta_i$?

Comment: @RonGordon: No. It is actually the angle between the two position vectors: i.e. if $(\theta_f, \phi_f)$ and $(\theta_i, \phi_i)$ correspond to $\hat{n_f}$ and $\hat{n_i}$, then $\cos{\theta}=\hat{n_f} \cdot \hat{n_i}$

Comment: In Math.SE, you have to make that explicit.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac Which sum do you want to compute? Over $m$ or over $\ell$?

Comment: I want to compute the $l$ sum, the $m$ sum has been done using the addition theorem for spherical harmonics.